# Looping background process with django

Tags: django, background, monitoring

I'm doing monitoring work with django. The program required to have a looping-forever sitting in background to process receiving data and update to database.

The job could be worked by writing a python script, and run in background with, for example, supervisord. However, I prefer the solution with django itself; that's the server process stay in a loop, listening for incoming packet.

Any suggestion would be high value and appreciate. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Run a seperate thread? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: yes. currently, I use a separated thread from django. This approaching may keep the collecting part away from django; however, leads to 2 database, which's unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

In case you feel that Celery is a bit oversized for your needs you could also define a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that lives forever and waits for your incoming packet.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Celery which works with Django and has support for long running tasks among other features.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lukedupin/django_posix_spawn

Using management commands in conjunction with this allows you to run django tasks that don't block your website.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a loop that is "django-aware" and already using celery for async tasks then
[celery-eternal](http://celery-eternal.readthedocs.io) might be a good fit. Only caveat is that you must use redis as the celery results backend.